# Responsive works only in dev tools, not in the actual site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to say first that I'm new to web dev, so maybe there's an obvious error I can't catch in my code... My problem is that the responsiveness of the site works only while I'm trying it in the dev tools, but in the actual site, there's a section that doesn't resize along with the others (section1 actually). This happens whit the tablet.css, because mobile and desktop work almost fine. I'm starting to have the doubt that maybe even mobile.css has this problem because I can't make the browser window so small, so I rely on the dev tools. I honestly can't figure why... I've tried in different browsers (Brave, FF Developer Edition, Microsoft Edge) and the story is the same.
I leave you my code, I use three CSS for mobile, tablet, and desktop, since I thought with media queries it would have been too complicated.
[with dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYl4C.png)
[in the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVPnu.png)
HTML:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="it" dir="ltr">

    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Domine:wght@400;700&family=Lora:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500&family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="icon" href="images/alebacce.ico">
    <link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
    <link href="tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 957px)" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Bacce's Angle</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <nav class="navflex">
        <img class="logo" src="images/alebacce.png" alt="a logo representing html tags">
        <ul class: "menu">
          <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/assas/Desktop/All/Coding/Projects/baccesangle/baccesangle.html#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#chisono">Chi sono</a></li>
          <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
          <li><a href="#interessi">Interessi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#chiamami">Contattami</a></li>
        </ul>
        <input id="hamburger" type="checkbox">
        <label for="hamburger"></label>
      </nav>

      <div class="main">
        <picture>
       <source 
          media="(min-width: 650px)"
          srcset="images/webdevlr2.png">
       <source 
          media="(max-width: 465px)"
          srcset="images/webdevlr2mobile.png">
       <img src="images/webdevlr2.png" 
       alt="Welcome on my site!">
    </picture>
        <div class="welcome">
          <p>
            <h1><strong>ALESSANDRO BACCELLI</h1></strong>
          </p>
          <p><em>Work in progress</em> WEB DEVELOPER</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="divide first">
      <div class="heading">
        <h1 id="chisono">Chi sono</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="section1">
        <div class="profile">
            <picture>
       <source 
          media="(min-width: 650px)"
          srcset="images/profiledef.png">
       <source 
          media="(max-width: 465px)"
          srcset="images/profiledefmobile.png">
        <img src="images/profiledef.png" alt="A picture of me">
    </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="biography">
          <p>Un ragazzo genovese di 24 anni, laureato in <em>Scienze della Comunicazione</em> da sempre appassionato di
            tecnologia e digitale. <br><br> Ho recentemente scoperto
            la mia passione per la programmazione grazie ai corsi di <strong><a
                href="https://www.start2impact.it/" target="blank">start2impact</a></strong>,
            iniziando il mio viaggio nel mondo di Html, CSS e via discorrendo... <br><br>
            Per quanto la strada sia ancora lunga ho fiducia nel futuro, questo sito vuole infatti essere l'inizio di un
            lungo percorso.</p>
             <div class="download">
        <button><a href="https://mega.nz/file/VNpETSiI#Z93X88NF5A-YwNvlLlN1qDqH9wesivKVRnLwK7WF9Hs" target="blank">Scarica il mio CV</a></button>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>



      <div class="divide colordifferent">
      <div class="heading margin">
        <h1 id="skills">Skills</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="section2">
        <div class="hard">
          <h2>Hard skills</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Inglese fluente</li>
            <li class="modifiedli">HTML</li>
            <li class="modifiedli">CSS</li>
            <li>Canva</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="soft">
          <h2>Soft skills</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Autonomia</li>
            <li>Fast learner</li>
            <li>Empatia</li>
            <li>Ascolto attivo</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="divide">
      <div class="heading bottomodif">
        <h1 id="interessi">Interessi</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="section2">
        <div class="inte hard">
          <ul>
            <li id="programmazione">Coding</li>
            <li id="foto">Fotografia digitale</li>
            <li id="grafica">Grafica</li>
            <li id="discover">Scoprire nuove cose</li>
            <li id="cucina">Cucina</li>
            <li id="videogiochi">Video-games</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="ressi soft">
          <ul>
            <li id="self">Self-growth</li>
            <li id="mind">Mindfulness</li>
            <li id="fit">Fitntess &amp; Health</li>
            <li id="storia"><span class="history">Storia e Antropologia</span></li>
            <li id="book">Lettura</li>
            <li id="eco">Ambiente</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

      <footer id="chiamami">
        <div class="foot"></div>
        <div class="foot contact"><a href="mailto:ale.baccelli@libero.it" target="_blank">E-mail</a><span class="not"><br></span><span class="bracket"> &nbsp; |&nbsp; </span><a
            href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alessandro-baccelli1996/" target="_blank">Linkedin</a><span class="not"><br></span><span class="bracket"> &nbsp;|&nbsp; </span><a
            href="https://talent.start2impact.it/home/student_index" target="_blank">Start2impact</a><br>
          <br> ALESSANDRO BACCELLI 2020 &#169;</div>
        <div class="foot"></div>
      </footer>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Style.CSS (desktop)

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: #E5DDC8;
        color: #1F1F1F;
    }

    /* width */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 10px;
    }

    /* Track */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: #EBFDFF;
    }

    /* Handle */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: #B1C5E7;
    }

    /* Handle on hover */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: #7699D4;
    }

    h1,
    h2 {
        font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
        color: #141414;
    }

    #hamburger {
        display: none;
    }

    .navflex {
        display: flex;
        background-color: #004369;
        font-size: 130%;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .logo {
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: 150px;
    }

    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: right;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    nav ul li a {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 0px 25px;
    }

    nav a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    nav a:visited {
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .main {
        display: flex;


    }

    .welcome {
        display: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 3em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #1F1F1F;
    }

    .welcome h1 {
        white-space: nowrap;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .main img {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .divide {
        height: 900px;
        margin-top: 120px;
    }

    .heading {
        font-family: "Montserrat",
            "Helvetica",
            "Arial",
            sans-serif;
        color: #141414;
        font-size: 200%;
        margin-bottom: 80px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .section1 {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 958px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .profile {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .biography {
        align-self: center;
        font-size: 140%;
        margin-left: 80px;
    }

    .biography a {
        color: #01949A;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .biography a:hover {
        color: #004369;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .download {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .biography button {
        font-size: 130%;
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #01949A;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .biography button a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .biography button a:hover {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #004369;
    }

    .biography button:hover {
        background-color: #004369;
    }

    .section2 {
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 auto;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        font-size: 200%;

    }

    .colordifferent {
        background-color: #E5F9E0;
        padding-top: 120px;
    }

    .margin {
        margin-bottom: 145px;
    }

    .hard h2,
    .soft h2 {
        margin-bottom: 25px;

    }

    .section2 ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-bottom: 140px;
    }

    .section2 li {
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        ;
    }

    .section2 ul li::before {
        content: "\2705";
        margin-right: 25px;
    }

    .section2 ul .modifiedli::before {
        content: "";
    }

    .section2 ul #programmazione::before {
        content: "‍";
    }

    .section2 ul #foto::before {
        content: "";
    }

    .section2 ul #grafica::before {
        content: "";
    }

    .section2 ul #discover::before {
        content: "️";
    }

    .section2 ul #cucina::before {
        content: "‍";
    }

    .section2 ul #videogiochi::before {
        content: "";
    }

    .section2 ul #self::before {
        content: "";
    }

    .section2 ul #mind::before {
        content: "‍♂️";
    }

    .section2 ul #fit::before {
        content: "";
    }

    .section2 ul #storia::before {
        content: "";
    }

    .section2 ul #book::before {
        content: "";
    }

    .section2 ul #eco::before {
        content: "♻️";
    }

    .bottomodif {
        margin-bottom: 110px;
    }

    footer {
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 350px;
        background-color: #004369;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 130%;
    }

    .foot {
        width: 33.33333%;
    }

    footer a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    footer a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .not {
        display: none;
    }
```

```
 Mobile:
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 90%;
    width: 100%;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    display: none;
}

#hamburger {
    visibility: hidden;
}

label,
label::before,
label::after {

    width: 100px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;

}

label::before {
    content: "";
    transform: translateY(-30px);
}

label::after {
    content: "";
    transform: translateY(30px);
}

#hamburger:checked+label {
    width: 0px;
}

#hamburger:checked+label::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px);
}

#hamburger:checked+label::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px);
}

.logo {
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.main {
    display: block;
}

.main img {
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: static;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.welcome {
    display: none;
}

.divide {
    height: fit-content;
    width: 100%;
}



.section1,
.section2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: initial;
    overflow-y: auto;

}

.profile img {

    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.biography {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.hard,
.soft {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.hard h2,
.soft h2 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.hard ul,
.soft ul {
    text-align: left;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;

}

.hard ul li,
.soft ul li {
    padding-left: 65px;
    text-indent: -65px;
}

.inte,
.ressi {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ressi ul {
    margin-bottom: 150px;

}

.history {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.bracket {
    display: none;
}

.not {
    display: unset;
}
```

```
Tablet:
```

```css
body {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .divide,
    .section1 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .first {
        height: 1200px;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .section1 {
        width: 90%;
        display: block;
    }

    .profile {
        margin-bottom: 70px;
    }

    .biography {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .biography button {
        margin-top: 70px;
    }
```

```
Thanks everyone for the help!
```

Comment: For Firefox its "Ctrl + Shift + M" There you can choose the resolution. Using Media Queries is actually easier and more efficient then you solution. That way you only need one CSS file and can select then specific changes you want to make. For example if you want to have the same font size,  you write it outside of meida queries and it will apply to everything undepending of the screen width.

Comment: PS: Why its also not working for you to check is following thing: `max-device-width` it will only check the width of the screen panel not the actually browser size. Use `max-width` and `min-width` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really! Everything works finally fine now! The problem as you said was the "device" in-between width declaration. Just a quick question about media queries if I could, can I just copy and paste mobile and tablet CSS under the main .css as media queries?

Comment: P.S I want to take your second comment as the answer to my question, how can I do it?

Comment: Not really worth as an anwser as it is only a wrong tag used. Comparable with a spellign error. Thats why I also choose to give this as an comment instead of an anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you main issue has been fixed, I try to adress your question from the comments how to use media queries.

You only use one css file for everything. For tablet and mobile devices you use the media queries as below. You start a media query with `@media` followed by `only screen` to adress only screens. Then you apply rules like `and (min-width)` and/or `and (max-width)` followed by the css opening tag `{` and closed with the css closing tag `}`. inbetween the css the same way you write it normally.

```css
/* your normal css here that should apply to every screen width as well as your desktop css that is not covered with the media queries for mobile and tablet */

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 480px) { /* <-opening tag media query */
    /* your mobile css here 
       as example: */

    .class { /* <-opening tag css selector */
      background-color: blue;
    } /* closing tag css selector */
    
    #id { /* <-opening tag css selector */
      background-color: red;
    } /* closing tag css selector */

} /* <-closing tag media query */

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 481px)
  and (max-width: 957px) { /* <-opening tag media query */
    /* your tablet css here 
       as example: */

    .class { /* <-opening tag css selector */
      background-color: blue;
    } /* closing tag css selector */
    
    #id { /* <-opening tag css selector */
      background-color: red;
    } /* closing tag css selector */

} /* <-closing tag media query */
```